# How to compile single gwt module using maven?

Tags: gwt

I have different module.gwt.xml files in my application, every time when i do a change in one module required to compile all modules again. Is there a way to compile single module using maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup modules to compile in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    <configuration>
    <!-- mode>headless</mode -->
    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
    </modules>
    <!-- <includes>**/*GwtTest.java</includes> -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. One more query i have, is there any way to compile single module with out touching the pom.xml file( Any maven goal? ).

Comment: I suppose it should be gwt:compile -Dmodule=your_module